# how to unset the iterm proxy

Tags: terminal, iterm, proxy

when I am using this command to install flutter in macOS Monteney, shows error:

```
$ fvm install 2.5.0                                                                                                                                                       ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Flutter "2.5.0" is not installed.

Installing version: 2.5.0...
Cloning into '/Users/dolphin/fvm/versions/2.5.0'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7890 after 4 ms: Connection refused

Could not install 2.5.0

Please run command with  --verbose if you want more information

(base)
```

how to disable the iterm proxy? I did not found the the env proxy setting:

```
~ ⌚ 0:35:22
$ env|grep proxy                                                                                                                                                          ‹ruby-2.7.2›
(base)
```

this is the system proxy setting:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your proxy variables are upper case?